# How to fix UISearchController search bar resizing when focused?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchcontroller, visual-glitch

I am trying to implement a UISearchController with a UITableView inside of a small popup screen like this: 
[Image displaying a popup with a UITableView and UISearchController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH3JV.png).
However, when the search bar is focused, it moves up and becomes wider, as shown here:
[Image displaying a glitched search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCKuj.png).
I have found one other post about this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55704967/how-to-resizing-issue-of-uisearchcontroller-searchbar-when-focused), but the accepted solution did not seem to fix the problem.
For reference, I am using a modal segue displaying over full screen. There is a content view in which the tableView and titleLabel are subviewed. Here is the relevant code for the popup view controller.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

var items = ["Test", "oewrghp", "wopqet", "vbsjadsf", "rweoghp", "bmwehth", "pqeojnh"]
var filteredItems = [String]()
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissTapGesture(gesture:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.3)

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = .white
    searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = .clear
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

    titleLabel.text = "Search"

    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.reloadData()
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:))))

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: have you tried `self.definesPresentationContext = true` ?

Comment: Yes, it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Starting from iOS 11, you should use `self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController` instead of `tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar`, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46436067/1014048) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `UISearchBar` instead of a `UISearchController`

Something like:

```
let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 44))
```

Hope this helps someone!